# Pytest asserting from another function's callback

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I am using pytest to test an airplane state transition. I am testing the `landing()` function that is predefined and calling it from another function. It looks something like this:

```
def landing():
    airplane_actions.decrease_altitude(ft=10000)
    time.sleep(30)
    airplane_actions.decrease_altitude(ft=5000)
    time.sleep(30)
    airplane_actions.decrease_altitude(ft=0)
```

In my testing module, `test_plane_actions.py`, I am calling this `landing()` function, however, I want to be able to assert the altitude values before each sleep.

test_plane_actions.py

```
def test_plane_actions():
    # Do some setups
    # assert
    plane_actions.landing() # I want to assert the altitudes in here from this function.
```

Is there a way to have the landing() function callback the `test_plane_actions.py` module during each sleep period and make an assert during each sleep period? Or perhaps a delayed assert? Let's assume we cannot decompose the `landing()` function and I want to be able to just call it in the `test_plane_actions.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one approach would be to patch out the `sleep` function

here's a small example using [`unittest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html)

```
from unittest import mock

def test_plane_actions():
    expected_values = iter([10000, 5000])

    def sleep_but_actually_assert(s):
        assert plane_actions.ALTITUDE == next(expected_values)

    with mock.patch.object(time, 'sleep', sleep_but_actually_assert):
        plane_actions.landing()
```

this also has the nice side-effect that your test doesn't take 60+ seconds to run

Comment: So with the `sleep_but_actually_assert` function, you are replacing the sleep with just an assert? What if I want the sleep in there (as well as the assert) to simulate the transition?

Comment: you could do that, though I don't know why you'd want your tests to be slow when they could be _fast_

Comment: I'm using selenium to test front end transitions and sometimes the rendering is slow to appear so I want to give it some time before I do the assert.

Comment: usually you're best to use `wait_for_*` and such